# Where can I see profiles in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, user-profile, asp.net-profiles

Is there a place like ASP.NET Configuration, where you can see the profile info of the users, in ASP.NET MVC 3 ??

Comment: "profile info of the user" - Could explain it? what info

Comment: I mean, additional info stored with the profile provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built in to MVC to see application or system users.  You'll have to roll your own.

Also, be clear whether you mean application or system users.
http://ayende.com/blog/121857/system-users-and-application-users